# SQL Server - Get by some equal fields in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Given this table as example

```
A (varchar(50), not null)
B (varchar(200), not null)
C (varchar(100), not null)
D (varchar(100), not null)
```

I would like to design a GET stored procedure that uses A and/or B and/or C in this way:

- The stored procedure fails if A and B and C are all null but it works with any other combination

Right now I have this stored procedure already working with A and B and C all mandatory, D is optional. I would like to change it with the specs above. More detail below:

```
SET @ParamDefinition = '
             @A varchar(50)
            ,@B varchar(200)  
            ,@C varchar(100) 
            ,@D varchar(100) 
'
```

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * 
               FROM
                    db.MY_TABLE
               WHERE
                    A = @A
                    AND B = @B
                    AND C = @C' 

if @D is not null set @SQL = @SQL + ' AND D = @D'
```

Comment: See [Kitchen Sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) by @AaronBertrand

Comment: "fail" and "return no rows" are very different things - choose your words more carefully. And you should parameterize your queries (not use string concatenation) to avoid sql injection vulnerabilities.